# Android data crunching

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a Android application which crunches data from large files, every time doing this takes more time to start my application what is the solution to keep the crunched object alive every time, even the application is closed.

Comment: Maybe you can save the crunched data (the result) and then just load it, instead of processing all the data again

Answer (score 0):

you need to **save** it before closing the application but, you have many cases:

in case of data not shared with other users, you can use 
**first**:
if the data size is small and unique you can use [sharedPrefernce](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) to store it and this is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) to learn how to use it too

**Second**, if the data is too large and different values for each record you can use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)

in case of the data must be shared with other users you have to use an online database or firebase for that.